# How do I restore the Templates folder in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, templates

I deleted the "Templates" folder some time ago. Yesterday I made new Templates folder and I created a template for an empty document, but it's not working.

Does someone know how to restore the Templates folder, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, this folder is empty.

It is declared for Gnome Shell in this file

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Where should stand the line

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

Of course, the Template Folder name depends on your locale and language

If the line has been removed because off the deleted folder, you will just have to create a new one and add the line.

Comment: Do I need to reboot after the change?